# how to know if a bundle product does not have stock of the simple product that makes it up

Tags: magento2.4.3

I have a problem and it is that if in my bundle product, one of my simple products that composes it is not found, it continues to appear as a product and it shouldn't, I want it to show the out of stock message if it doesn't meet the condition.
[image]

Comment: By default, Magento won't allow you to add to the cart if one of the child products is out of stock. Looks to me it's your theme issue?

Comment: yes, but it does allow adding and the idea is that it does not allow and in that case I want to show a span just like in the simple products out of stock

Answer (score 0):

You need to override listing block and write you logic, you can check for all simple product associated with bundle product and then check for the stock availability. and accordingly you can show/hide the add to cart button or just set product status to out of stock. if you need code please ask, I will provide you the snippet.

Comment: i writte a block in app/design/frontend/Myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php
and
app/design/frontend/Myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/Block/Product/View/AbstractView.php

to show in PLP app/design/frontend/Myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

but it doesn't show anything, I'm doing something wrong

Comment: have you added preference for your block? if not then please create ect/di.xml file and add preference to your block

Comment: i add the app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php file, but ow show or get in my templates?

Comment: Have  you created preference in di.xml file

Comment: how preference? i dont know

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/override-block-model-controller-magento-2/   you can follow this link